# SQL Creating a temp table for this Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I want to create a temp table to store this query so that I can then update another table.

```
SELECT SaginawUtilityData.ServiceFrom, SaginawUtilityData.ServiceThru, 

BillingMonth = dbo.fn_MonthWithMostDaysInRange(ServiceFrom, ServiceThru),

SaginawUtilityData.Usage, SaginawUtilityData.UtilityCharges

FROM SaginawUtilityData

JOIN tblMEP_CustomerAccounts
ON SaginawUtilityData.AccountNumber = tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.AccountNumber

JOIN tblMEP_Customers
ON tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.CustomerID = tblMEP_Customers.ID

JOIN tblMEP_UtilityCompanies
ON tblMEP_UtilityCompanies.ID = tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.UtilityCompanyID

JOIN tblMEP_Meters
ON tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.ID = tblMEP_Meters.CustomerAccountID
WHERE tblMEP_Customers.ID = 43
```

It would be great if you can just do the update: this is the other table and the columns I want to insert from the table above into this one:

```
SELECT tblMEP_MonthlyDATA.CycleStartDate, tblMEP_MonthlyDATA.CycleEndDate, 

tblMEP_MonthlyDATA.BillingMonth, tblMEP_MonthlyDATA.Consumption,

tblMEP_MonthlyDATA.Charge

FROM tblMEP_MonthlyData
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note, if there is a better way that I can insert the data into the tblMEP_MonthlyData table other than creating a temp table then please let me know. I am new to SQL.

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` data or `INSERT` data. On the other hand, the columns on the first `SELECT` don't seem to be the same columns you have on your `tblMEP_MonthlyData` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain whether I really understand what you're asking but I think you're asking how you can put the data from the top query straight into the table columns shown in the bottom query, so:

```
INSERT tblMEP_MonthlyDATA (
    CycleStartDate, CycleEndDate, BillingMonth, Consumption, Charge)
SELECT 
    SaginawUtilityData.ServiceFrom, 
    SaginawUtilityData.ServiceThru, 
    dbo.fn_MonthWithMostDaysInRange(ServiceFrom, ServiceThru),
    SaginawUtilityData.Usage, 
    SaginawUtilityData.UtilityCharges
FROM SaginawUtilityData
    JOIN tblMEP_CustomerAccounts ON SaginawUtilityData.AccountNumber = 
                                           tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.AccountNumber
    JOIN tblMEP_Customers ON tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.CustomerID = tblMEP_Customers.ID
    JOIN tblMEP_UtilityCompanies ON tblMEP_UtilityCompanies.ID = 
                                           tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.UtilityCompanyID
    JOIN tblMEP_Meters ON tblMEP_CustomerAccounts.ID = tblMEP_Meters.CustomerAccountID
WHERE 
    tblMEP_Customers.ID = 43 --or other set of conditions
```

Hope this helps (or is at least vaguely relevant to what you want to know)